# Ориентация макета на экране эмулятора Android под API Q и 29

Tags: orientation

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при повороте эмулятора макет остается в книжной ориентации. Причем эмулятор показывает индикацию смены ориентации, но макет при этом ориентацию не меняет. Однако вопрос в том, что на эмуляторе под API 22 всё работает нормально. Проблемы на эмуляторах под API выше 26(конкретно я пробовал на Q и на 29).
Кто в курсе почему такое или я где то что то пропустил?

Comment: Под API 26 тоже всё нормально работает без дополнительных танцев с бубном.

Comment: Все возможные настройки проверял, в манифест лазил,  сотворил несколько AVD  с разными настройками-бесполезно. Пока в ианифесте 
в активити жестко не прописываешь оринтейшн, макет не реагирует на смену ориентации устройства с вертикальной на горизонтальную. По итогу "спустился" до эмулятора под API 26.